# Find process attempting to connect to Android Device

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

Without ADB Running or any application listening on port 5037, `lsof | grep "5037"` is empty

```
COM:platform-tools user$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
** daemon still not running
error: cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: Connection refused
```

If I kill ADB or restart the computer, then try to run my app from Android Studio

```
10:03:39 E/adb: error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
10:03:39 E/adb: ADB server didn't ACK
10:03:39 E/adb: * failed to start daemon *
10:03:39 E/adb: error: cannot connect to daemon
10:03:39 E/ddms: '/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

Genymotion SDK directory: `/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/`

Android Studio SDK directory: `/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/`

This wasn't happening before, it started happening yesterday (after a year without issues).

OS: `macOS Sierra 10.12.3`

platform-tools: downloaded right from the website today

`./adb version`

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Revision 5943271ace17-android
```

I assume something is trying to connect **to** or **from** my Android device, because If I restart the computer, without adb running, I plug in the device via USB and then go to `/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` and issue `./adb devices`

It shows

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
adb E 03-23 11:11:01  1239 20079 usb_osx.cpp:333] Could not open interface: e00002c5
adb E 03-23 11:11:01  1239 20079 usb_osx.cpp:294] Could not find device interface
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

After a while of having my Android Device connected via USB I get this notice

[image: The connected device is unable to access data]

Purged Android Studio and the SDK completely, then rebooted, still getting the same problem

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same issues with same version of adb after last update. i have search in whole internet and try all method not working also i tried changing port but still same issues hope somebody here help us or to show us how to get install old version of adb

**Updated**

I solve the problem buy uninstall platform-tools
and download lower version from this link for (**MACOSX**)

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r25.0.3-darwin.zip

make sure your sdk folder have platform-tools empty file what you do is unzip downloaded and move all files to platform-tools and restare your mac it will work 100%

:)

Comment: DUDE! You are a LIFESAVER! After days spent trying to figure out what I was doing wrong, this tip INSTANTLY resolved the problem! I'm working in a purely Android Studio/OSX environment with no Genymotion BS to deal with--just AVDs and real Android devices. Wow. What a relief! I can now use adb commands without any issues at all! Thanks for the link, that made things very easy. I just went to my platform-tools folder, zipped what was there and left the archive in place while removing the binaries. Then added all the 1.0.36 tools and *INSTANTLY* life was back to normal. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: really glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message because I had another project opened in Visual Studio at the same time I was launching the ADB in Android Studio. Closing the Visual Studio solution fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

I'd uninstall "Commander One" first and see where that takes me, file transfer protocol is famous for causing problems.